# Object is null after being initialized in a method

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and I have a problem in my code.
I start by initializing the Maze object to null because I don't know which will be the choice of the user. It is initialized in the method createMaze() but when I call printMaze it is null.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static final String EXITGAME = "EXIT";
    public static final String PRINTBOARD = "PRINT";
    public static final String CREATEMAZE = "UPLOAD";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Maze maze = null;

        menu(maze,in);
    }

    private static void menu(Maze maze, Scanner in){
        String option = in.nextLine();
        while(option.toUpperCase() != EXITGAME){
            switch(option.toUpperCase()){
                case PRINTBOARD: printMaze(maze); break;
                case CREATEMAZE: createMaze(in,maze); break;
            }
            System.out.println();
            option = in.nextLine();
        }
    }

    private static void printMaze(Maze maze){
        if(maze != null){
            int maxX = maze.getxSize();
            int maxY = maze.getySize();

            for(int x = 0; x < maxX; x++){
                for(int y = 0; y < maxY; y++){
                    System.out.print(maze.getMazeRepresentation(x, y));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Maze is undefined");
    }

    private static void createMaze(Scanner in, Maze maze){
        if(maze == null || !maze.getGameStatus()){
            int x = in.nextInt();
            int y = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
            char rawMaze[][] = new char[x][y];

            maze = new MazeClass(x,y);

            for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
                createMazeLine(in,i,y, rawMaze);
            }
            maze.createMaze(rawMaze);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Maze already defined.");
    }

    private static void createMazeLine(Scanner in, int lines, int y, char[][] rawMaze){
        String line = in.nextLine();    

        for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){
            rawMaze[lines][i] = line.charAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You should make use of the  [OO](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm) nature of Java. Get all the inputs for the Maze from a user then, when the user inputs a command to initialize the Maze then you make a Maze object.

Comment: How, I need to wait for the command to be UPLOAD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Java when you pass parameter to the method (i.e. Maze maze `createMaze(Scanner in, Maze maze)` it is a value of reference to the maze.
In other words in your case:

- there is a null value.
- there is a reference to that null called null
- in call to the method value of that reference passed (let say address) as pramemter
- in method call there is a parameter variable which holds value of that reference

Java does not have "parameters by reference" or pointers conception.

So, when inside the method `createMaze` you do `maze = new MazeClass(x,y);`

you assign new object maze reference to the reference parameter variable.

But your initial null value and reference to it outside of method stay untouched and object you created inside method destroyed after method done.

In short, all you need is:

```
private static void menu(Maze maze, Scanner in){
    String option = in.nextLine();
    while(option.toUpperCase() != EXITGAME){
        switch(option.toUpperCase()){
            case PRINTBOARD: printMaze(maze); break;
            case CREATEMAZE: maze = createMaze(in,maze); break;
        }
        System.out.println();
        option = in.nextLine();
    }
}

private static Maze createMaze(Scanner in, Maze maze){
    if(maze == null || !maze.getGameStatus()){
        ... yuor code ...
        maze.createMaze(rawMaze);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Maze already defined.");

    return maze;
}
```

Of course code can be written in more clear style, but main point is

**new value assignment to the method parameter inside the method does not replace value of variable passed as parameter in the caller**

Comment: So now I can't go back to main because I will lose the Maze object, is that correct ? Thank you very much...

Comment: Yes. If you'd like to have it in main do the same there. I mean return new maze to main as well.

Comment: There is another technique. You cannot replace object, but you can change it's properties. So, you can have a holder with maze as property. Then you can assign new maze to it anywhere and you can pass holder down the stack and do not return maze from every method. It means you can do it as you first tried, but with holder, not maze it-self